# В тексте include-а url не обрабатывается

Tags: laravel, шаблоны

Подскажите, используя  в laravel 5.4 темплейты 
и имея большой кусок кода  делаю с инклудом:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    @include('layouts.top_navigation')
```

И в этот файл копирую(В  phpstorm через меню Paste Simple) текст

```
    <div class="top-left-part"><a class="logo" href="index.html"><b><img src=" url('images/template/eliteadmin-logo.png') " alt="home" /></b><span class="hidden-xs"><img src=" url('images/template/eliteadmin-text.png') " alt="home" /></span></a></div>
```

И в браузере блок

```
{{ url('
```

не обрабытывается и осстается текстом и ссылка неправильна...

А как правильно?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сам и разобрался что в имени темплейта не указал .blade.